# Version 22.04 and HARDWARE raid installation

Tags: hardware, raid

I have two PCs with hardware RAID controllers, up to version 20.xx I could install correctly with the disks configured as a RAID1 array, but with version 22.xx, the installation fails, I was able to complete the installation with the RAID controller disabled and with a single disk (did not try 2 disks, but I'm sure the problem lies with the hardware RAID)  Any clues?

I tried to set the two disks to AHCI (non-RAID) but got the same error, so I took off the two disks and reformatted them on another system using the disk tool and a USB to SATA interface and tried a new install, that time, it worked, so I reformatted them again, set them to RAID again and got the same error. It looks like the installation medium isn't made to work with hardware RAID arrays! –

I do a normal install from a USB 8Gb stick. I tried 18.xx and 20.xx both installed correctly but with either 22.04 or 22.10, it fails with a message saying "gave up waiting for root file system device " and it drops to the BusyBox v1.30.1 built-in shell (ash)

Obviously, something broke with the way 22.xx deals with hardware RAIDs during the installation. I have 2 PCs with two different motherboards, both with built-in RAID controllers and both have the same problem, they install on fresh disks but without the RAID controller being active.

I tried installing with a dedicated RAID controllers, an AAR2610SA (PCI) with 2 1Gb drives and also a RocketRaid 2640X4 (PCI-e), while the first one "seemed" to work because it "saw" the disks, it hung half way in and the second one just did not appear to be seen by the installation program. I tried to set the dive as RAID-1, RAID-0 and JBOD, no success!